# Curl to rest template using "clientId:clientSecret@servername/oauth/token"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, resttemplate

I have a question about how Can I send this curl with rest template? 
Thanks in advance

curl -XPOST "server-client-id:server-client-password@localhost:8080/oauth/token" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=server-client-id&client_secret=server-client-password"

Edited:I had done it. But it didnt work

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceRestApi.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userRestTemplateAuthServer")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
@Value("${userServer.client.id:server-client-id}")
private String clientId;
@Value("${userServer.client.secret:server-client-password}")
private String clientSecret;
@Value("${userServer.url:info-server:info-rest-password@localhost:8080/oauth/token}")
private String url;

/**
 * Get auth token from User server
 *
 * @return
 */
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1500))
@Cacheable(value = "userServerToken")
public String generateAuthToken() throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Obteniendo Token del servidor de users");
    try {
        GenerateAuthTokenRequestDTO requestDTO = new GenerateAuthTokenRequestDTO(clientId, clientSecret);
        GenerateAuthTokenResponseDTO responseDTO = this.restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestDTO, GenerateAuthTokenResponseDTO.class);
        return responseDTO.getAccessToken();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        throw new UserServerConnectionException();
    }
}


/**
 * Flush the cache for userServerToken
 */
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30 * 60 * 1000, initialDelay = 500)
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = "userServerToken")
public void flushUserServerTokenConfig() {
}
```

And this is the stacktrace when I do the test.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 12: info-server:
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory$DefaultUriBuilder.build(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory.expand(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.java:191)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:683)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:435)
at com.nsu.duhire.webapi.info.rest.UserServiceRestApi.generateAuthToken(UserServiceRestApi.java:45)
at com.nsu.duhire.webapi.info.InfoApplicationTests.testConnectionWithAuthServer(InfoApplicationTests.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 12: info-server:
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3057)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
... 36 more
```

The github repo to the auth server is: https://github.com/NSU-IO/AuthenticationServer

Comment: What is exact problem? Show what you've done so far

Comment: I edited the question. Its probably that I am in a  bad way